# Return node.js sql result to other file

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, pug

I want to create a Website where I can display results from my mysql database.
I finished the website and the sql query, but I am stuck to return my SQL result.
Here is my code for my server with nodejs to display my pug file:
app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const router = express.Router();

var db=require("../node_js/db.js");


app.set("view engine","pug");

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Application started and Listening on port 3000");
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  sql_result=query("SELECT * FROM test");  //here should i get my sql result
  res.render("test",{title:"Card",details:sql_result});
});
```

My databse connection code:
db.js

```
function query(sql){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  var connection=db;
  connection.query(sql,function(err,rows,fields){
    if(err){
      return reject(err);
    }
    resolve(rows[randomRow(0,rows.length)]);
    });
  });
}

query("SELECT * FROM SONGS").then(function(rows){
  console.log(rows);
}).catch((err)=>setImmediate(()=>{throw err;}));
```

I struggel to return 'rows' from query to my app.js file and use it in 'app.get("/").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the first file you should require your other file to be able to use its functions.
and since it returns a promise you can use await to get the result.

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const query = require("./db.js");
const router = express.Router();

var db=require("../node_js/db.js");


app.set("view engine","pug");

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Application started and Listening on port 3000");
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  let sql_result=await query("SELECT * FROM test");  //here should i get my sql result
  res.render("test",{title:"Card",details:sql_result});
});
```

and the db.js

```
module.exports = function query(sql){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  var connection=db;
  connection.query(sql,function(err,rows,fields){
    if(err){
      return reject(err);
    }
    resolve(rows[randomRow(0,rows.length)]);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you mate. I am new to await functions.